# Mapping from OWL ontology to OrientDB Graph Database

Tags: java, orientdb, owl, graph-databases, owl-api

I am working with OWL ontology and I have to import an owl ontology into OrientDB graph database. Is there a solution implemented to parse OWL ontology and map it to a OrientDB Graph or convert owl ontology to labeled property graph and import it into OrientDB?

I know there are similar solutions for Neo4J graph database.

https://github.com/flekschas/owl2neo4j

https://neo4j.com/blog/using-owl-with-neo4j/

For OrientDB?

Comment: As far as I know, no there isn't. But you could simply reuse the converter of owl2neo4j and adapt it to the input syntax of OrientDB.

Comment: You can map it into neo4j and than use neo4j to OrientDB importer: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-Neo4j-Importer.html

Comment: Did you try this  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/W4TTKrhZpaY  ?  The import tool to neo4j import only the TBox; is this okay for you ?

Comment: If you want to use OWL, have you considered using an RDF database? You're not going to get acceptable performance from systems that were not designed to support OWL.

Comment: @AKSW  I saw that owl2neo4j only converts the class hierarchy; instances are ignored. For my own purposes, I need to convert everything. So, I'm using the code in this post https://neo4j.com/blog/using-owl-with-neo4j/ but I got the follow problems for the instances https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46606072/problems-querying-owl-ontology-through-owl-api

Comment: @Galigator What do you mean by TBox?

Comment: The TBox are the assertion on the model : https://www.aaai.org/Papers/Workshops/1996/WS-96-05/WS96-05-004.pdf   Basically you can view it as your data-model without data.

Comment: Can it be a good way convert an owl ontology in rdf/xml format to GraphML and import it into OrientDB through GraphSail?